# Catch exceptions with bunyan

Tags: node.js, winston, bunyan

I am using bunyan for logging my node.js code.

But I was wondering is there anything like `winston`'s `ExceptionHandlers:[]` in bunyan?

Answer (score -3):

No. There isn't because it's your job to handle all the possible scenarios where error can happen and catch them and log.

Comment: "this isn't a convenience feature b/c you're write perfect code" etc. is rarely helpful. Bunyan supports streams in a plugin-style system, meaning you invariably introduce others' code into the logging flow.  There isn't a practical way afaik to handle those exceptions, so even if you're "doing your job, " you can still get an unhandled exception.